# Clicking on ListWidget's item first time raise an error?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I want to ask you a question. When I click on listwidget's item first time, I see there are some text lines in application output:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::setClipping: Painter not active, state will be reset by begin
```

Is it an error? How can I do to hide/disable these text lines in app output?

Answer (score 0):

Those are warning messages of QT.

You are probably having a problem with an image cause **type == 3**

Check this out for [device types](http://cep.xor.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/d0/d1e/class_q_internal.html#14a4c68c9d5acd100b6ab7fc3ecfefd83cad109c6bd7eb633490511b834961bb).